# Order from Amazon with Ruby Mechanize - Bypassing Javascript Hurdles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to create a scraper with Mechanize that places an order from Amazon using my affiliate link. The goal is to allow users to place an order on my site which contains products fetched using the Amazon Product API and allowing them to order it from my site without being redirected to Amazon. Unfortunately, Amazon does not have an API to accomplish the ordering part, so I built a scraper and am so close but need help getting past the final page!

The page I am stuck on is the page that allows you to select a credit card and then simply click continue to complete your order. I think Amazon uses some kind of javascript to load in some elements dynamically. When I use my browser to get to this page, I see the credit card I've added with the radio button on it pre-selected and all i need to do is hit continue to checkout. If I use mechanize to get there then copy the contents of `puts agent.page.body` into an editor and preview it, I notice that everything is there except the element containing the credit card with the radio pre-selected.

Here is the code in it's entirety. You can copy/paste this into ruby console and you will make it to the last page. I would extremely appreciate if someone more experienced in Mechanize can help me get past this page!

(You will need to fill your own amazon login creds to use this..)

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.cookie_jar.clear! #clear cookies

#Page 1 (Confirm add to cart)
page1 = agent.get("http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?ASIN.1=B0002YIQEQ&Quantity.1=1")
form = page1.forms[1]
button = form.buttons.first
page2 = agent.submit(form,button)

    #Page 2 (view/update cart)
    agent.page.form('cartViewForm').checkboxes.first.check 
form2 = agent.page.form('cartViewForm')
form2.checkbox.check
checkoutForm = page2.form_with(:id => "gutterCartViewForm")
checkoutBtn = checkoutForm.buttons.last
page3 = agent.submit(checkoutForm, checkoutBtn)

    #page3 (Sign in)
form3 = page3.form('signIn')
form3.email = 'EMAIL HERE'
form3.password = 'PASSWORD HERE'
page4 = agent.submit(form3, form3.buttons.last)

    #page4 (Where do you want your items shipped?)
form4 = agent.page.form_with(:action => "/gp/buy/shipaddressselect/handlers/continue.html/ref=ox_shipaddress_add_new_addr")
form4.enterAddressFullName = 'NAME'
form4.enterAddressAddressLine1 = 'ADDRESS'
form4.enterAddressAddressLine2 = ''
form4.enterAddressCity = 'CITY'
form4.enterAddressStateOrRegion = 'ST' 
form4.enterAddressPostalCode = 'ZIP'
form4.enterAddressPhoneNumber = 'PHONE'
page5 = agent.submit(form4, form4.buttons.last)

    #page5 (Choose your shipping options)
    agent.page.form_with(:id => "shippingOptionFormId").checkboxes.last.check
    agent.page.form_with(:id => "shippingOptionFormId").submit

    #page 6 (gift wrapping form)
   agent.page.form_with(:id => "GiftPageContiueForm").radiobuttons_with(:class => "itemGiftWrapSelect").each do |t|
    t.check
  end
  agent.page.form_with(:id => "GiftPageContiueForm").submit

 #page7 (This is where I am stuck - continue-top is indeed the right button.
  agent.page.forms.each do |t|
    if t.button_with(:id => "continue-top")
      form = t
      button = t.button_with(:id => "continue-top")
    end
  end
  agent.submit(form,button)
```

Comment: Is help not the point of this website? I feel simply the code I have so far is of value to the community..I'm sure I'm not only person needing to auto-order from amazon using their own aff link. P

Comment: SO is for specific questions, not free general help. That's why I say you should consider hiring someone.